# How to convert a character string ("17NOV03") to a date to be used for arithmetic

Tags: r, date, regression, dplyr

I have a column full of dates from 2003 and 2004. Currently, the column is a string that looks like the following (see column 6):

[image]

I want to convert that column to a date, but I'm not sure how to because of the abbreviated month in the middle of the string. I've tried mutating a number of ways, but can't seem to get it to work.

Ultimately, my goal is to use diff_time() to show how many days from January 1st 2003  each entry is. For instance, January 3rd, 2003 would be displayed as 3, and January 5th, 2004 would be displayed as 370 and so on and so forth. Here is what I'm working with at the moment:

```
data$contact_date1 <- as.Date(data$contact_date1, format="%d-%m-%y")

data$contact_date1 <- difftime(
  as.POSIXct("2003-01-01 12:00:00"), 
  data$contact_date1, 
  unit = "days")
```

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct string for the format argument? How about "%d%b%y"?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, you should use `%b` to decode your dates.

Have a look at the `?strptime` help page for this.

```r
first.date <- as.POSIXct("2003-01-01 12:00:00")

weird.dates <- c("17NOV03","06May02")

?strptime

times <- as.Date(weird.dates, format = "%d%b%y")

difftime(time1 = first.date, time2 = times)
#> Time differences in days
#> [1] -319.5417  240.4583
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use the package `lubridate`; its function `dmy` converts your data format into the `yyyy-mm-dd` format:

```
library(lubridate)
round(difftime(dmy(data$contact_date1),"2003-01-01", units = "days"), 0)
Time differences in days
[1]  9 45
```

To add the days to the dataframe:

```
data$days <- round(difftime(dmy(data$contact_date1),"2003-01-01", units = "days"), 0)
```

Toy data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  contact_date1 = c("10JAN2003", "15FEB2003")
)
```